# Find values greater than using hstore and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql, pg, hstore

I am storing product information, including the release year of the product, using hstore and postgresql in rails. Now I would like to be able to query for all products that was released before or after a specific year. I am able to query for all records containing the year field in the 'data' hstore column using:

```
Product.where("data ? 'year'")
```

Due to hstore the year value is stored as a string. Therefore, I have tried to type cast the year to an integer in order to find records with years greater than/less than X:

```
Product.where("(data ? 'year')::int > 2011")
```

However, this does not seem to work, I always get an empty array of results in return. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think the operator your are looking for is `->`. So, try `where("(data -> 'year')::int > 2011")`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html

Comment: Using -> works perfectly! You can add it as the answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think the operator your are looking for is `->`.

So, try this : `where("(data -> 'year')::int > 2011")`

(from jO3w's comment)